# Why is coefficient of series solution of ODE always a multiple of each other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Example:$y''+py'+qy=0$

If ordinary point, plug in $x^r$, if regular singular point plug in $x^{n+r}$, we always get $a_{n+2}=F(n)*a_{n}$ but never $a_{n+2}=\rho *a_{n+1}+\phi*a_{n},etc.$

Answer (score 0):

For the example you give, even when $p$ and $q$ are constant, you **do** get a relation involving $a_{n+1}$: substituting a series assumption for $y$, you obtain
\begin{equation}
 (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} + p (n+1)a_{n+1} + q a_n = 0.
\end{equation}
If, for $p$ and $q$ functions of $x$, you do happen to find a recurrence relation involving only $a_{n+2}$ and $a_n$, it's purely coincidental.